# How to set css for first div, if there's no second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I want to set *`border-bottom-left-radius`* and *`border-bottom-right-radius`* for *`<div class="first">`*, only if there's no *`<div class="second">`*.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using CSS only. Here is an example to do it with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
if ($('.second').length == 0) {
    $('.first').css('border-radius', '0 0 2px 2px');
}
```

With `$('.second').length == 0` you check, wether an element of class *`second`* exists or not. You can read more about [jQuery's `css()` function on the documention](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would do this:

`.first:last-of-type{ border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px; }`

The style is just applied if the div first is the unique.